# SELECT MAX MIN value of temperature CURRENT DAY but last YEARS from ALL history

Tags: mysql, date, group-by, max, min

I would like to ask you for help with SQL. 
I have got database with where  are 4 colums. ( time, temp, hum, press )
In this table are data from my meteo station.
Right now in this table are 110000 rows with records from last 3 years.
I want get MAX and MIN values of temp from all last years in same day like today.

I know how get all temp data from last years in same day but I do not know what next :-D

```
SELECT temp 
FROM `table_name` 
WHERE (
    YEAR(time) < YEAR(CURDATE()) 
    AND MONTH(time) = MONTH(CURDATE()) 
    AND DAY(time) = DAY(CURDATE())
)
```

Sorry for my bad english.

Thank you

Comment: Hello Bebeno, welcome to Stack Overflow. SQL date functions are quite vendor specific. Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, sql-server, oracle...

Comment: Is `table_name` a placeholder for some table name? Otherwise, I don't know what the backticks are for.

Comment: yes `table_name` is placeholder for table name. Original table name is `U_sokolika`. It is not in english. For this reason I used table_name. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use date arithmetics and aggregation:

```
select min(temp) min_temp, max(temp) max_temp
from table_name
where 
    year(time) < year(current_date) 
    and month(time) = month(current_date) 
    and day(time) = day(current_date)
```

If you want the results by year:

```
select year(time) yr, min(temp) min_temp, max(temp) max_temp
from table_name
where 
    year(time) < year(current_date) 
    and month(time) = month(current_date) 
    and day(time) = day(current_date)
group by year(time)
order by year(time)
```

Comment: Hi . Thanks for your answer. This sql works but it is not what I look for. This sql get only max and min value from all rows which have year lower like current year, but I want get result something like  in year 2019 max = ..., min= ... ; 2018 max=... , min=...; 2017 max=... min=... and so on.    Thank you for your help